# Hibernate many to one mapping using one column which is in primary composite keys

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am now trying to use hibernate to retrieve data from mysql database. However, I encountered the org.hibernate.AnnotationException which alerted me that I cannot use single property. My code is as below, please have a look.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "master")
public class Master implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MasterPK id;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String emailaddress;

    ....

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "master")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Child> childs;

    ....
    // Getter and setter
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child implements Serializable {

    ....

    @Column
    private String code;

    @Column
    private String isGolden;

    @Column
    private Date startServiceDate;

    @Column
    private Date endServiceDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_a", referencedColumnName="id_a")
    private Master master;

    ....
    // Getter and setter

}


@Embeddable
public class MasterPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="id_a")
    private String idA;

    @Column(name="id_b")
    private String idB;

    ...  
    //Classes generated by JPA Tools e.g. getter, setter, comparator
}
```

I try to map master table and child table by using master.id_a and child.id_a while id_a and id_b are the primary key of master table. Therefore, hibernate threw exception and I cannot start my apps. But I still want to map two table by id_a only because child table does not have id_b. And the design is that each row in master table may be mapping to multiple child table. May I have some suggestions for this situation? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you "swapped" the entities, that is the composite pk you defined seemd actually a primary key of a typical child table.
Can you post the schema of the actual tables ? This could be help

Comment: thanks for your help. I have updated my code. And actually the child table is just one of the extension tables to store the extra details from master table

Comment: And master table and child table only share the FK id_a. Master table use id_a and id_b as primary key (id_a is unique too but need to combine id_b as primary key for other purpose, the tables cannot be changed). Child table only has id_a column.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite confused by this design,  what are the purpose of combining id_a and id_b as pk in master table when the `id_a` alone is a good pk ? Anyway the issue you have with hibernate is that the child entity have to reference all columns of the master's primary key not just 
`id_a`.